# Unable to get element under other elements

Tags: html, css

I have an issue formatting some HTML. Basically I have a large number of listboxes which are hidden once the page is loaded, and have placed them in HTML tables for now. I am aware that this is not good practice, but this is how I have received them and since there are over 100, I cannot realistically change their HTML code.

I would like for the `</hr>` and two buttons on the right of the image, to appear **under** the listboxes.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5W4nv/) of the code.

How can this be formatted for the buttons to appear underneath, regardless of the height taken up by the listboxes? i.e. they will always appear underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell the browser to ignore the floating set by the the `div` surrounding the `table`:

```
#divButtons{
    clear:both;
}

#divButtons input[type="submit"]{
    float:right;
}
```

Please note that this solution "inverses" the order in which your buttons are displayed. You might need to change their position in your HTML.

Comment: @Liam, it doesn't align the buttons to the right but it does move the `<hr>` under the table, as requested in the question.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on what this does? It seems to have worked

Comment: The `<div>` containing the buttons is affected by the `float: left;` set by the `<div>` containing the table. That means that the browser _floats_ all the content to the left and therefore your buttons are rendered in the place remaining by the table. The `clear: both;` instruction tell the browser that the floating of the element is not desired anymore and that the div should be displayed as per default (i.e. single `block`, taking all the width available).

Comment: @DotNET: Please note the additional comment: the `float: right;` applied to the submit buttons changes their order. The first button encountered (`btnResetSelections`) is first floated to the right (right margin); the second button (`btnApplyFilter`) is then floated to the right, but "hits" the first button and gets rendered on the left. You can change this reversing the order of your buttons in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this

```
#divButtons{ width:100%; float:left }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9BBKp/

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on what this does exactly?

Comment: Basically makes the div that contains the buttons the width of the parent element( the one that contains them ) so that it can't be placed next to the listboxes

Answer (score 0):

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5W4nv/)

try this:

```
<form>
    <div style="padding-top: 2%; float:right;clear:both;"> <b>Select Product:</b>

        <select name="cmbProducts" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;cmbProducts\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="cmbProducts" style="width:250px;"></select>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 50px;">
        <hr />
        <div>
            <div class="selection-panel">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Test</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select size="4" name="listBoxTerminalType" id="listBoxTerminalType" class="list-box"></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="selection-panel">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Test</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select size="4" name="listBoxVoltageAndSuitableLamp" id="listBoxVoltageAndSuitableLamp" class="list-box"></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div id="divButtons" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" name="btnResetSelections" value="Reset Selections" id="btnResetSelections" />
        <input type="submit" name="btnApplyFilter" value="Apply Filter" id="btnApplyFilter" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and css:

```
.list-box {
    width: 250px;
}
.selection-panel {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
#divButtons {
    float:right;
    clear:both;
}
```